# How to pass arguments to my application that include the - symbol on gdb?

Tags: c, gdb, command-line-arguments

I need to pass some arguments to my application,that include the - symbol. The problem is if I pass `gdb a.out -foo baa`, the gdb understand that the arguments are for it, and not to my application. How to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `gdb -q a.out`
   inside gdb:
2. `run -foo baa`

   Tip: -q option for gdb suppresses the introductory copyright messages.

Comment: Recommendation: Read pzanoni answer for more options, I provided the simplest one.

Answer (score 4):

Option 1:

- `gdb --args ls /tmp`

Option 2:

- `gdb ls`
- `set args /tmp`
- `run`

Option 3 (didn't know about that, thanks Ahmed):

- `gdb ls`
- `run /tmp`

Maybe there are others?